# SonarQube Unable to blame file pom.xml

Tags: git, maven, sonarqube

I am suddenly having trouble running a SonarQube analyses on a project that previously ran fine (I'm running it through Jenkins).  It's giving me an error, "Unable to blame file pom.xml".  (We're using GIT).

This makes no sense... since the last successful run I've only added two lines to the pom, and I'm the only one who has ever committed to the pom file.  The project is in our company's BitBucket Server, and I'm able to see the blame information there... so what could be causing this error?

I've included a snapshot of the stacktrace in the Jenkins log:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a JGit bug. Please refer to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499543

Comment: Well that's not comforting... said but has been around for over half a year and its status is still "NEW".  :P

Comment: The traditional way to get these things fixed is to check out the code and fix it yourself. Submit your fix back to the project. I've done this several times myself, particularly in the early Maven days.

Answer (score 1):

You may encounter this if you are performing a shallow fetch of your repository.  If not enough history is available, it doesn't seem to get enough information to annotate the source.